# how to see your step by step results for example in listings

Tags: c#

I am creating a plugin for Revit using c# . My question is how to see your results step by step . For example , when i am working on listings and arrays so how to see its result . Like i used to work in dynamo Revit and there when working on listings we used to connect watch with every node and we could see the results and values going in and out.

Comment: use background worker and call progress change event for update/print your result.

Comment: Actually i am new to programming , so can you explain your suggestion in detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are writing this in VS. Just use `Debugger.Launch();`, or set the break point where you want to see the results and watch your variables in "Locals" window.

Edit:

[image]

Set debugging point where you want to see your local variables. In this example, I want to see what values I have stored in list. (Without writing them into the console.)

Then start your program with debugger (F5 - usual shortcut).

[image]

On the left side of the window you see your local varibles, as you press next buttons on the bar on the top, you will see how your variables are changing as you progress. Please read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: yes i am writing in visual studio . Actually i am new to programming . I use break point to see whether line by line code is running or not . Can you explain your suggestion in detail

Comment: Thanks alot Oleg.